# R returning matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix, return

I'm trying to return a matrix from a function, but unable to understand why this returns an error.

```
  rdMatrix <- function (value = 0) {
  x <- diag(value)

  get <- function() return(x)

  x
  }
```

The output:

```
> rdMatrix(5)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1

> rdMatrix$get()
Error in rdMatrix$get : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
>
```

Can anyone please let me know what is missing here.

Thanks and Regards,
Balaji

Comment: Why do you have a function for `return`? Return means "STOP now and return whatever's inside the `()`". At soon as it's called, the function terminates.

Comment: i'm trying to return the matrix, this is a test function for my other project. My intention is to have rdMatrix$get() return x.

Comment: rdMatrix()$get : Error in rdMatrix()$get : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. it doesn't work, you can change the name get to anything else but still the same error

Comment: Have no idea what you are trying to do, but maybe this could suffice? `rdMatrix <- list(get = rdMatrix);
rdMatrix$get(5)`

Comment: If all you want to do is return the matrix, why not just `return(x)` rather than `get <- function() return(x)`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I want to store a matrix by initializing it and then get the stored value using another function

Comment: @RichardScriven sorry posting for the first time, hope now the question is clear. Can you please help to understand what is incorrect here.

Comment: @RichardScriven you now now understood the question, can you provide an answer before marking this question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're aiming for this:

```
rdMatrix <- local({
    get <- function() return(x)
    x <- NULL
    function (value = 0) {
        x <<- diag(value)
        x
    }
})

rdMatrix(5)
environment(rdMatrix)$get()
```

or maybe you'd prefer:

```
rdMatrix <- local({
    x <- NULL
    list(get=function() return(x),
         set=function(value=0) {
             x <<- diag(value)
         })
})

rdMatrix$set(3)
rdMatrix$get()
```

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to initialize without set()? like rdMatrix(3) instead of rdMatrix$set(3), what is the difference? how to modify this function to do that? TIA